# My GridView becomes scrollable even if there is much space left on the Page

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

I am using a simple Linear-Layout with lots of different views and a grid-view. But my problem is that I don't want my grid to be scrollable. I have enough space, at least in my phone and I am also using scroll-view. I just want my grid to not be scrollable, even if it makes my activity too much scrollable.

I can't post whole of my activity because it's too large. So, I am posting only the grid.

If you want anything else, feel free to ask for, I will post that also

```
  <GridView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/gridview_info"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:numColumns="3"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Pls expect late reply.. I am going to sleep and will go to school tomorrow. Will reply only after 6pm (Indian Standard Time)

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your Gridview  property `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Comment: It's too big...I can't

Comment: I thought to avoid this....now I m using ListView but it does not look much fine...but for now It's OK...And thanks to @KP for such fast answer even at midnight